# statistical test in r to show significant difference between groups

Tags: r, t-test, significance

I am working with small scale survey data in r.

I would be grateful for input on what would be best/most simple test to use to show any row-wise significance between group differences for a series of options (opt1-opt9). When my data is grouped/aggregated it looks like this (respondents can multi select options):

| opt | group1_count | group1_percent | group2_count | group2_percent | diff_% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| opt1 | 14 | 0.081395349 | 17 | 0.042821159 | 0.038574 |
| opt2 | 23 | 0.13372093 | 59 | 0.14861461 | -0.01489 |
| opt3 | 29 | 0.168604651 | 65 | 0.16372796 | 0.004877 |
| opt4 | 6 | 0.034883721 | 6 | 0.01511335 | 0.01977 |
| opt5 | 2 | 0.011627907 | 7 | 0.017632242 | -0.006 |
| opt6 | 38 | 0.220930233 | 88 | 0.221662469 | -0.00073 |
| opt7 | 37 | 0.215116279 | 98 | 0.246851385 | -0.03174 |
| opt8 | 11 | 0.063953488 | 25 | 0.062972292 | 0.000981 |
| opt9 | 12 | 0.069767442 | 32 | 0.080604534 | -0.01084 |

Would a t-test be valid here to show whether there are significant differences between group 1 and group 2? If yes, is there a simple way of generating this row wise in r? If not, do you have any suggestions?

Here is first 3 rows as dput:

```
structure(list(opt = c("opt1", "opt2", "opt3"), group1_count = c(14, 
23, 29), group1_percent = c(0.081395349, 0.13372093, 0.168604651
), group2_count = c(17, 59, 65), group2_percent = c(0.042821159, 
0.14861461, 0.16372796), percent_diff = c(0.03857419, -0.01489368, 
0.00487669099999999)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to compare the two groups in the first row, you can carry out a [two-proportion z-test](https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx). For instance in R:

```
result <- prop.test(x = c(14, 17), n = c(172, 397))
```

where `172` = sum(`group1_count`) and `397` = sum(`group2_count`)

Output:

```
2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(14, 17) out of c(172, 397)
X-squared = 2.758, df = 1, p-value = 0.09677
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.01105128  0.08819966
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.08139535 0.04282116
```

If you want to compare your proportions all at once, you can use a chi-square test:

```
data <- as.table(cbind(c(14, 23, 29, 6, 2, 38, 37, 11, 12),
                       c(17, 59, 65, 6, 7, 88, 98, 25, 32)))

chisq <- chisq.test(data, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  data
X-squared = 6.671, df = NA, p-value = 0.5787
```